# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index' in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

***Default.aspx***

```
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="typeHobby" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem style="display:none">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Sports">Sports</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="FineArt">Fine Arts</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox  ID="nameSport" style="margin:2px" CssClass="cap" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Details of participation">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="detailSport" style="margin:2px" CssClass="cap" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Distinction achieved">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="distSport" style="margin:2px" CssClass="cap" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,15}" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Whether still intrested">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="intrestSport" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem style="display:none">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="no">No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="addHobby" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click_Hobby" CausesValidation="false" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void ButtonAdd_Click_Hobby(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            addHobby();
        }

        protected void addHobby()
        {
         //   MessageBox.Show("add hobby");
            try
            {
                int rowIndex = 0;
                if (ViewState["HoobyTable"] != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("if true");
                    DataTable dtHobbyTable = (DataTable)ViewState["HoobyTable"];
                    DataRow drHobbyRow = null;
                    if (dtHobbyTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(dtHobbyTable.Rows.Count.ToString());
                        for (int i = 1; i <= dtHobbyTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            //extract the TextBox values
                            MessageBox.Show("loop");
                            DropDownList txh1 = (DropDownList)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("typeHobby");
                            TextBox txh2 = (TextBox)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("nameSport");
                            TextBox txh3 = (TextBox)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("detailSport");
                            TextBox txh4 = (TextBox)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("distSport");
                            DropDownList txh5 = (DropDownList)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("intrestSport");
                            MessageBox.Show("Hello" + txh1.Text);
                            drHobbyRow = dtHobbyTable.NewRow();
                            drHobbyRow["Slno"] = i + 1;

                            dtHobbyTable.Rows[i - 1]["hoType"] = txh1.Text;
                            dtHobbyTable.Rows[i - 1]["Name"] = txh2.Text;
                            dtHobbyTable.Rows[i - 1]["Detail"] = txh3.Text;
                            dtHobbyTable.Rows[i - 1]["Distinction"] = txh4.Text;
                            dtHobbyTable.Rows[i - 1]["Interest"] ="interest";

                            rowIndex++;
                        }
                        dtHobbyTable.Rows.Add(drHobbyRow);
                        ViewState["HoobyTable"] = dtHobbyTable;

                        hobbyGrid.DataSource = dtHobbyTable;
                        hobbyGrid.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("ViewState is null");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
            //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
          SetPreviousDataHobby();

        }
        private void SetPreviousDataHobby()
        {
            int rowIndex = 0;
            if (ViewState["HoobyTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["HoobyTable"];
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {

                        DropDownList txh1 = (DropDownList)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("typeHobby");
                        TextBox txh2 = (TextBox)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("nameSport");
                        TextBox txh3 = (TextBox)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("detailSport");
                        TextBox txh4 = (TextBox)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("distSport");
                        DropDownList txh5 = (DropDownList)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("intrestSport");
                        MessageBox.Show("type hobby" + dt.Rows[i]["hoType"].ToString());
                        txh1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["hoType"].ToString();
                        txh2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
                        txh3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Detail"].ToString();
                        txh4.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Distinction"].ToString();
                        txh5.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Interest"].ToString();


                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index'**
-> got an error like above in line:
*DropDownList txh5 = (DropDownList)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("intrestSport");*

(line from SetPreviousDataHobby() function)

Comment: Well the exception is self explanatory your array is out of range. Try debugging line by line see what it is missing and where .It is a very common array exception.

Comment: btw, `i` and `rowIndex` always have the same value, you could remove rowIndex

Comment: Column numbering starts at zero, so HobbyType is `Cells[0]` and `Cells[5]` does not exist, causing the exception

Comment: hello Krupa, can you confirm if one the answers below solved your problem, if yes, kindly mark as resolved

Answer (score 1):

*I believe this should point you in the right direction*

- *Rows* and *Columns* of `DataGrid` starts at *index* 0
- `hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5]` indicates that there are *6* columns, do you think that's true ?
- The error message simply indicates that you are accessing an index that is outside the limits of the data structure.
- You can validate how many `columns` are available at `row[0]` by `hobbyGrid.Rows[0].Cells.Count-1;` `Cells[5]` should not exceed this

  **OR**
- You can also check number of colums from table like  `int cols= dtHobbyTable.Columns.Count`

Answer (score 0):

Error is because, you are accessing cells from 1 through 5. so at Cells[5] its throwing out of range exception. Please modify your code to start from 0:

```
DropDownList txh1 = (DropDownList)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("typeHobby");
TextBox txh2 = (TextBox)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("nameSport");
TextBox txh3 = (TextBox)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("detailSport");
TextBox txh4 = (TextBox)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("distSport");
DropDownList txh5 = (DropDownList)hobbyGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("intrestSport");
```

**Side but related notes:**
1) There is another issue that you may encounter after fixing this error:
adding data row outside forloop. So, you are basically overwriting data row in for loop and adding just one row. Ignore me if that is what you expected. Otherwise, move the below line inside for loop.

```
dtHobbyTable.Rows.Add(drHobbyRow);
```

2) Another issue is you are running for loop on an item which you are updating. Instead its good to have for loop on hobbyGrid.Rows.Count.